# if $f(x)$ is absolutely integrable and piecewise-smooth then $xf'(x)$ is also absolutely integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Proposition:
if $f(x)$ is absolutely integrable and piecewise-smooth then $xf'(x)$ is also absolutely integrable**

This proposition made sense to me intuitively but I am not sure if it is correct (it came up in order to solve a different question in fourier analysis)

My attempt to prove:

Use Lagrange's IVP to get $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ with $0<c<x$ which implies $|xf'(c)|\leq|f(x)-f(0)|$.

My intention is to get rid of $c$ and $f(0)$ somehow and get something like $|xf'(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ which solves the problem (by the comparison theorem for integrals)

Comment: Do you know under what additional conditions it will be correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) says that
$$
\int xf'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=xf(x)-\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$